# How to echo the array of a sql consult into a html

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having trouble with an array, I don't know why it isn't showing on the HTML index.

`$db` is the stablished connection

The table structure is:

```
pedidos:
id, cliente_id, creacion, id, modificacion, precio_total, and status

productos:
id, nombre, descripcion, precio, descripcion
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?PHP
$sql=mysqli_query($db,"
    SELECT 'p.id', 'p.nombre', 'p.precio', 'a.cantidad', 'p.precio' * 'a.cantidad' AS total, 'a.id'
        FROM articulos_pedidos a INNER JOIN productos p 
        ON 'a.producto_id' = 'p.id'
            INNER JOIN pedidos pe
        on 'a.pedido_id' = 'pe.id' 
        WHERE pedido_id = 23")OR die("query is incorrect-........................");
            $a = $sql->fetch_assoc();
            $data_pedido = array(
                    'id' => $a['pedido_id'],
                'nombre' => $a['p.nombre'],
                'precio' => $a['p.precio'],
                'cantidad' => $a['a.cantidad'],
                'total' => $a['ptotal']
                );
?>

<?php echo $data_pedido['id']; ?>
<?php echo $data_pedido['nombre']; ?>
<?php echo $data_pedido['precio']; ?>
<?php echo $data_pedido['cantidad']; ?>
<?php echo $data_pedido['total']; ?>
```

Comment: Can you show your output please?

Comment: When you say *html index*, do you mean you have a file called `index.html`?

Comment: It does not output anything at all

Comment: yes the html file, actually is name index.php, down de code i write i start the html code

Comment: Alright - if you inspect the source code, do you see anything there? Does `error_reporting(E_ALL);` `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` output anything? Or [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)?

Comment: if you have a mysql gui like phpmyadmin, try running your query there and see what it outputs.

Comment: when i inspect the src, does not show anything. And when i run the query on sql console it actully shows up what im lookin for.

Comment: Show the output please

Comment: <html><head></head></html> it really does not show nothing, not on the browse nor the sql.log

Comment: print your array $data_pedido and check value is there

Comment: i tried <?php echo $data_pedido; ?> it outputs, "Notice: Array to string conversion" and also the word "Array", with a capital letter

Comment: use print_r($data_pedido); You cant use echo for printing array.

Comment: Array ( [id] => [nombre] => [precio] => [cantidad] => [total] => [test] => )

Comment: I think you cannot access `p.precio` as `$a['p.precio']`. You have to use [aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). Try to access `$a['total']` not `$a['ptotal']` in `$data_pedido` definition.

Comment: Have you checked your sql query in your phpmyadmin?

Comment: @Alan Whoops, I don't know why I haven't seen this before... You're using singlequotes around your column-names! Remove all of your `'` in the query - you aren't using any strings anyway. This query really shouldn't work in phpMyAdmin or other GUIs though because of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: After removing the single qoutes it show up Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a' in

Comment: Progress! Sounds like you're missing a variable identifier `$` in front of a variable somewhere. The error gives you a line to look at.

Comment: it show that its where the array start, should i enter a $before?

Comment: $query=mysqli_query($db,"
  SELECT p.id, p.nombre, p.precio, a.cantidad, p.precio * a.cantidad AS total, a.id
  FROM articulos_pedidos a INNER JOIN productos p 
  ON a producto_id = p.id
      INNER JOIN pedidos pe
      on a pedido_id = pe.id 
      WHERE pedido_id = 23")OR die("incorrect");
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $data_pedido = array(
     'id' => $row['pedido_id'],
     'nombre' => $row['pnombre'],
     'precio' => $row['p.precio'],
     'cantidad' => $row['a.cantidad'],
     'total' => $row['ptotal'],
     'test' => $row['']
     );
it show query is incorrect

Answer (score -2):

```
$data_pedido=array();
while($a = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {       
    echo $data_pedido['id']=$a['pedido_id'];
    echo $data_pedido['nombre']=$a['p.nombre'];
    echo $data_pedido['precio']=$a['p.precio'];
    echo $data_pedido['cantidad']=$a['a.cantidad'];
    echo $data_pedido['total']=$a['ptotal'];
}
```

Comment: at the end of while loop print the array and comment the output here